# Unwanted option passed to compiler

Tags: gcc, cmake, avr

I currently port all my AVR (microcontroller) projects from ugly Makefiles to (well, a bit less ugly) CMakeLists. My issue here is that even when I define CMAKE_C_FLAGS without CMake defaults some unwanted parameters are still passed.

CMakeLists.txt snippet:

```
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-std=c99 ...")
```

I would expect now that CMake calls the compiler like this:

```
gcc -std=c99 ... <input files> -o <output file>
```

What happens (`make VERBOSE=1`) is this:

```
gcc  -std=c99 ...  <some input files> -o <output> -rdynamic
```

How did that `-rdynamic` get there? I would ignore it if the gcc for the target would support it, but as it doesn't know the `-rdynamic` option... well I'm a bit screwed here...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known issue. Try adding:

```
set(CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_LINK_C_FLAGS "")
```